# Add total values in dictionary by reduce function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning the `reduce` function and it's capabilities however I cannot seem to figure out how to use it with dictionaries.

For example, I have the following dictionary:

```
const scores = [
    {
        team: 'A',
        score: 20
    },
    {
        team: 'B',
        score: 17
    },
    {
        team: 'C',
        score: 23
    },
    {
        team: 'D',
        score: 13
    }
]
```

I want to add all the values `score` in the neatest way possible, I have tried approaching this myself with:

```
const test = scores.reduce((first_item, second_item) =>{
  console.log(first_item.score, second_item.score)
    return first_item.score + second_item.score
  }
)
```

However, it doesn't add up the values, and it seems to only work for the first two values in the dict. What's an easier alternative that would work for larger dictionaries on a smaller line of code? as I see it, I would have to keep including variables in the `reduce` function to match the number of keys.

Comment: You really need to [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The arguments passed to the callback aren't first value, second value … and couldn't be or you could only ever do anything useful with arrays that were exactly two elements long!

Comment: `scores.map(x=>x.score).reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0)` can be more flexible with multiple properties.

Answer (score 1):

The reduce function works like so:

```
reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => { /* ... */ } )
```

so what you need to do is:

```
const test = scores.reduce((acc, item) =>acc + item.score, 0)
```

Please read the documentation MDN is a really good website for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

fistful you should pass `previousValue, currentValue` arguments instead of `first_item, second_item`. I really suggest you to read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Your code is not returning the total score because reduce you're trying to sum number and undefined (Do console.log() inside of the reduce you will understand  more).

You can make something like that;

```
  const scores = [
    {
      team: "A",
      score: 20,
    },
    {
      team: "B",
      score: 17,
    },
    {
      team: "C",
      score: 23,
    },
    {
      team: "D",
      score: 13,
    },
  ];

  const totalScore = scores.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return { score: a.score + b.score }; // returns object with property x
  });

  console.log(totalScore.score);
```